# ASP.Net MVC5 - Value Cannot Be Null

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Why am I seeing this?

The reason I'm asking is the modal is displaying perfectly fine and this particular dropdown list is populated with the correct values, meaning that ViewBag.StatusCodes is not null ... the dropdown has 4 values as expected.

[image: Value Cannot Be Null]

The main controller that launches a Bootstrap modal is setting the viewbag correctly.  I have verified the stored procedure is returning the current results.  If I put ViewBag.StatusCodes into the watch it shows as NULL, but the page is displaying as expected and I don't get errors are runtime.

[image]

As far as I have read, partials can read the ViewBag from the parent.  And the weird thing is, if I run the page, the partial displays this dropdown CORRECTLY, but when I run it under the debugger, it breaks, saying the ViewBag that is populating the dropdown is null.

How is the dropdown displaying correctly (4 values, as expected) yet VS thinks this is NULL?

The page I'm running without the debugger has all changes saved and builds without errors.

The names are correct, the stored proc returns two fields, "StatusCode" and "StatusDesc".  None of these are NULL.

There is no other code that is populating this.  This is the only line that fills the dropdown, which displays fine if I don't run under the debugger.  I'm lost here.

Comment: btw, is your model null?

Comment: I have added a picture of the dropdown.  The source looks fine.

Comment: I usually (always) do DropDownListFor(model => model.StatusCode), not Desc. http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/11/dropdownlistfor-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint and determine what IS null?

Comment: I have.  It says ViewBag.StatusCode is NULL.  I can't see how that's possible when at runtime it looks fine.  Like I said everything is saved, build succeeds, looks fine in the browser, fails under the debugger.

Comment: Let us see the code in your controller.

Comment: Sure, the controller for the main page is just setting a ViewBag property from a stored procedure: ViewBag.StatusCodes = dbDetails.Database.SqlQuery<Status>("EXEC dbo.DUAL_GetStatusCodes").ToList();

Comment: The stored procedure returns the expected results, and like I said the dropdown displays fine, so I have no idea why visual studio is breaking on this and why the ViewBag.StatusCodes shows as NULL in the watch window but that is what is populating the dropdown.

Comment: View Detail shows "{"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: items"}" ... how is that possible if it displays correctly?  The resulting HTML source looks fine.